# Spring JUNIT datasource autowiring

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-jdbc

I got Spring Java Config style configuration with 2 datasources:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBConfig {

    // main db
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .addScript("classpath:schema.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:data.sql")
                .build();
    }
    //db for test    
    @Bean(name = "testDataSource")
    public DataSource testDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .addScript("classpath:schema.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:test-data.sql")
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(){
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }
```

But when I autowire that datasources in my Test class and run him: i got the same result:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DBConfig.class)
@Transactional
public class JdbcTest {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testDataSource")
    private DataSource testDataSource;

    @Test
    public void findRealDb() {
        String rowCount =  jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select message from messages", String.class);
        System.out.println("real db "  + rowCount);
    }


    @Test
    public void findTestDb() {
        String rowCount = (new JdbcTemplate(testDataSource).queryForObject("select message from messages", String.class));
        System.out.println("test db " + rowCount);
    }
}
```

So as result method findTestDb() logs same rowCount string as findRealDb() , but as you see them use different datasources to build jdbcTemplate.

[image]

Comment: Although it looks like you are using 2 datasources and thus 2 seperate databases you are not. You are using 2 datasources but a single database.

Comment: Seems like wiring the two data sources is only helping you verify the correct wiring.  What is the use-case of wiring the non-test data source into the tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test code will be autowiring by type. I'm surprised you don't get a non-unique bean exception.

The trouble is you have two beans, one of which is qualified and one of which isn't.

You are much better off using Spring profiles and assigning the test datasource to a test profile and the production datasource to a default profile, then setting the active profile for your test case to be test.

Here's an example:

http://fahdshariff.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/spring-3-javaconfig-unit-testing-using.html

note that you can put the @Profile annotation on an individual bean or a configuration class.